# How to create a density or heatmap with 2D data array?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, geopandas, density-plot

I need some help making a density/heatmap with lat/long coordinates. I've been able to plot these points by themselves on a map (see below), but need to see the density.

Here is the code I have.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy import io
df = pd.read_csv("/data.csv")
df_lightning = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Latitude': df['LAT'],
     'Longitude': df['LON']})

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
usa     = geopandas.read_file('path/states.shp')
counties = geopandas.read_file('path/Tx_CntyBndry_Detail_TIGER500k.shp')
ax = usa.plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')

plt.plot(df_lightning.Longitude, df_lightning.Latitude, '.')

ax.set_ylim(25, 30)
ax.set_xlim(-98, -91)

plt.ylabel('Latitude (deg)', fontsize = 14)
plt.xlabel('Longitude (deg)', fontsize = 14)
plt.title('Source Locations of Combined TCs', fontsize = 16)
```

Here is the plot I've made:

[image: Plot I've made]

This is what my dataframe looks like. Only using Lat and Lon:

[image: This is what my dataframe looks like. Only using Lat and Lon]

Any suggestions on what I could try to make a density plot? I've tried countourf, pcolor, pcolormesh amongst others, but they all require a third dimension to plot with. Is there a way to do without this? I'm still new to coding so any help is welcomed. Thanks!

Link to csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fPRhgBXTlULmsFcRV-3ivkxlRSD_bGVa/view?usp=sharing
States .shp file used: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uWTbVONNq08d6LrPGBNkpikFBEX9AJQn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Easiest way would probably be to create a grid and then count the points in each grid cell and use that to make the heat map. So your three dimensions would be lon and lat for your grid, plus your counts for each grid cell.

Comment: there are multiple techniques.  is your data publicly available?  pls add link to in in question

Comment: @RobRaymond it’s not publicly available but I could link/attach the csv file to this question, is there a way to do that?

Comment: put csv on GitHub or a cloud storage platform and provide link to it in the question

Comment: have you tried [`ax.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/stats/hist2d.html#sphx-glr-plot-types-stats-hist2d-py) or [`ax.hexbin`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/hexbin_demo.html)? they should both do what you're looking for.